# How to read a certain line in the txt file by using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net and this is what I have in my test.txt file:

```
My name is james

I was born in Melaka

*

I like to eat fish

#

My hobby is riding
```

I want my function to read this file between the symbol * and #

This is my function and how I'm going to edit it to put the condition in ?

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim fileReader As String
   fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Users\user\Documents\text.txt")
   txt2.Text = (fileReader)
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that tries to locate or read the part you're trying to get. Did you forget that part of the code?

Comment: I had edit my question. sorry for the dumb there.

Comment: So what have you tried? Like Ken said, you are not even trying to search the string for the * and # symbols. You have to put in effort in order to receive any help.

Comment: I'd use the `ReadAllLines` method instead of `RealAllText`, since it returns a string array, it will make it easier for you to search through it.

Comment: Um, no. Adding a sentence that adds "how do I edit it to put the condition in?" is not an effort to do something. Did you search this site for previous questions about `[vb.net] find text in string` or anything like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can do everything* with LINQ:

```
Dim result = From line In File.ReadLines("c:\path\to\your\file.txt")
             Skip While line <> "*"
             Skip 1
             Take While line <> "#"

For Each line In result
    ' Do something '
Next
```

[*]: Not true

Comment: in some simple task linq is not the best choice

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression it's a quick solution, with `(\*)([\s\S]+)(\#)` pattern you can find whatever between `*` and `#`

```
   Dim fileReader As String
   fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Users\user\Documents\text.txt")
   txt2.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(fileReader,"(\*)([\s\S]+)(\#)").toString()
```